# The convergence of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sin(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Is this definite integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sin(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t$ convergent?

If it is convergent please calculate what it converges to, and if not would you please give an explanation why it is not?

Comment: Not every integral has an answer. Are you possibly misinterpreting what is being asked of you (if this is a problem given to you)? Solving the integral and proving its convergence are very different things.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. The problem is NOT asking for an exact result but asking for testing for convergence. I'll edit my question ASAP.

Comment: Your function behaves nicely... save for values close to $t=0$ where $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sin(t)}$ goes to positive infinity. The only thing you would need to do then is to show that the integral (which will be positive because the function is positive) does not also go to infinity.

I recommend first tackling the question: when does $\int_{0}^{\pi}x^p dx$ converge, in terms of $p$?

Then, the division you have is fairly similar to $t^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, so if you could replace $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sin(t)}$ by a more well known expression such as that one it could be of some help.

Comment: You can as well apply the limit test which is more relevant for the integral of $(t^{1/2}-\sin t)^{-1}$ where the comparison with $t^{-1/2}$ is not possible directly. The only singularity occurs at $0$ and $$\lim_{t\to 0}{t^{1/2}\over t^{1/2}-\sin t}=1$$ Since the integral of $t^{-1/2}$ do does the integral of $(t^{1/2}-\sin t)^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\sin(x)\ge 0$ for $x\in [0, \pi]$ then $$\sqrt{x} + \sin(x) \ge \sqrt{x}$$ on $[0, \pi]$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! By direct comparison method, it seems that the question is solved! (It is not an assignment though, but only a textbook exercise)